# Python String Starts with #

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list contains multiple urls and some string like #skipsideNav, #content. I'm separating out urls from those strings

```
if link.startswith('/'):
    local_urls.add(link)
elif link.startswith(base_url):
    domain_urls.add(link)
elif link.startswith("#"):
    ignore_urls.add(link)
else:
    foreign_urls.add(link)
```

However those starting with # is not being ignored somehow getting included in the output of foreign_urls

```py
   for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'): # select the url in href for all a 
    tags(links)
    if link.startswith('/'):
        local_urls.add(link)
    elif link.startswith(base_url):
        domain_urls.add(link)
    elif link.startswith("#"):
        ignore_urls.add(link)
    else:
        foreign_urls.add(link)

   print(foreign_urls)
```

Comment: Thats unusual. Can you post which links are not passing through `link.startswith("#")` ?

Comment: Could you post few sample urls?

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility seems to be white spaces before *#*. Did you check that?